# VSCode muestra carpetas duplicadas cuando pongo etiqueta html a ./

Tags: html5, vscode

Cuando trato de usar cualquier etiqueta que requiera rutas me aparecen `carpetas y archivos duplicados` ej.

> 2 index.html, 2 carpetas css

Pero solo en el visual porque cuando comparto la carpeta todos la ven normal

Comment: Este tipo de sintomas se generan usualmente cuando hay algún servicio como iClud u otro drive donde se están sincronizando.
Sin lugar a dudas no es un comportamiento por defecto del VSC.
Si utilizas iCloud puedes configurarlo apropiadamente o agregar a tu carpeta root del proyecto .nosync, ejemplo si se llama ejercicio10 quedaría así: ejercicio10.nosync.

Comment: Otra cosa que puede generar ese comportamiento e incluso hay un ticket en Microsoft es una versión antigua de VSC, en mi caso por ejemplo actualmente tengo la 1.71.1, verifica si la que tienes es una versión actual o instala una versión más nueva si es necesario.

Comment: Antes no me pasaba, pero actualice es VSC hace 1 semana y apareció este error

Comment: tengo la version 1.73.0